# How to merge all WAV files appearing on the same line in a list?

Tags: bash, audio, sox

I have a plain text file containing a list of WAV files:

```
0001.wav 0002.wav
0003.wav 0004.wav
0005.wav 0006.wav 00007.wav 0008.wav
0009.wav
0010.wav
0011.wav 0012.wav 0013.wav
0014.wav
0015.wav
```

These same files are in the same folder as the plain text file.

According to [How to merge several audio files using sox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634036/how-to-merge-several-audio-files-using-sox), I can use `sox -m <filename> <filename> <filename>` to merge any files together in `sox`. How can I use `sox` to merge all of the files listed on the same lines into one file, with the output files named in sequence, e.g.:

- 0001.wav 0002.wav → m0001.wav
- 0003.wav 0004.wav → m0002.wav
- 0005.wav 0006.wav 00007.wav 0008.wav → m0003.wav

Comment: Neither answer shows how to output to the newly sequenced filename.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to to do this with:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
i=1

while IFS=" " read -r -a line
do
     sox ${line[@]} m$(printf "%04d" $i).wav
     let i+=1
done < $filename
```

Here we read the file given as the first paramenter to the script into an array `line`, where `IFS=" "` says to use a space for the delimeter, if you are using tabs you should change this to `IFS="\t"`.

`${line[@]}` expands the array of input file names.

`m$(printf "%04d" $i).wav` says to specify a file name of the format mXXXX.wav, where `printf` is used to get the formatting.

`i` is the variable you iterate for the output file names.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see if it was possible to do this in one line.  I think I have it here.

```
cat <file> | xargs -L 1 printf "%s\n" | xargs -I {} sox {} m%4n.wav gain 0 : newfile
```

`cat` will read your file ( replace `<file>` with your filename) and pipe into `xargs`, which will treat each line of the file as space separated arguments.

Use `print` to print each arg on a new line.

Use `xargs` again to recombine the arguments (each on a new line), using the `-I` argument so we can put the arguments at the front of the`sox` command and pass additonal arguments (you can't use `-I` and `-L` at the same time, otherwise you'd only need one `xargs`).

Use the `sox` gain filter set to 0 so we can chain the pseudo newfile filter to create a new file each time with the pattern `m####.wav`

Edit: nevermind, this doesn't quite work.  It's still sending each file as an individual argument.  Maybe someone with more command line-fu can do better.  The script approach is probably more readable anyhow.